# How to boost occurence of an entire term in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

For a definition like this

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "standard", charFilters = {
    @CharFilterDef(factory = HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class) },
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "words", value = "/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/english_stop.txt")}),
        @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "1"),
            @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "15")})
    }),
```

I have two documents like `5456`
and 
`5459 In the Jungle`, with search term like 5459 I would like to return the 2nd document higher then the 1st one in results. But the `fieldNorm` for 2nd is lower then 1st one.

How can I boost a document when the entire search term appears in a document compare to where it only appears partially?

---

I think this looks relevant https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#_customizing_lucene_s_scoring_formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Disables effect of lengthNorm
 */
public class CustomSimilarity extends ClassicSimilarity
{
    public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
        return state.getBoost();
    }
}
```

In spring yaml config

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.similarity : com.example.search.CustomSimilarity
```

Comment: can somebody from hibernate/lucene comment on whether this fine?

Answer (score 0):

I would use two fields, one without ngrams and boosted, the other with ngrams but not boosted.

```
@AnalyzerDefs({
    @AnalyzerDef(
        name = "ngram",
        charFilters = {
            @CharFilterDef(factory = HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)
        },
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "words", value = "/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/english_stop.txt")}),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "15")
            })
        }
    ),
    @AnalyzerDef(
        name = "standard",
        charFilters = {
            @CharFilterDef(factory = HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)
        },
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class, params = {
                @Parameter(name = "words", value = "/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/english_stop.txt")})
        }
    ),
})
@Indexed
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Fields({
        @Field("myfield_ngram", analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "ngram")),
        @Field("myfield_standard", analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "standard"))
    })
    private String myField;

    // ...
}
```

Then query this way:

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder()
        .forEntity( MyEntity.class )
        .overridesForField( "myField_ngram", "standard" ) // Don't generate ngrams when querying, it serves no purpose
        .get();
Query query = qb.keyword()
        .onField( "myField_standard" ).boostedTo(2.0f)
        .andField( "myField_ngram" )
        .matching( "5459 In the Jungle" )
        .createQuery();
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this code.